# select only nan column from dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

movie_rating_T.iloc[:,5:6]

```
critic  Toby
title   
Just My Luck    NaN
Lady in the Water   NaN
Snakes on a Plane   4.5
Superman Returns    4.0
The Night Listener  NaN
You Me and Dupree   1.0
```

let say I want to select the  Nan column only

```
Just My Luck
Lady in the Water
The Night Listener
```

How to use dataframe nan to extract only nan value?

```
critic  Toby
title   
Just My Luck    NaN
Lady in the Water   NaN
The Night Listener  NaN
```

.['title'] is not working

===============================================================
movie_rating_T.iloc[:,5:6]

```
critic  Toby
title   
Just My Luck    NaN
Lady in the Water   NaN
Snakes on a Plane   4.5
Superman Returns    4.0
The Night Listener  NaN
You Me and Dupree   1.0
```

df_MovieRatingT[df_MovieRatingT['Toby'].isnull()]

```
critic  Toby
title   
Just My Luck    NaN
Lady in the Water   NaN
The Night Listener  NaN
```

==============================================================
df =  DataFrame(ratings)

```
    critic  title   rating
0   Jack Matthews   Lady in the Water   3.0
1   Jack Matthews   Snakes on a Plane   4.0
2   Jack Matthews   You Me and Dupree   3.5
3   Jack Matthews   Superman Returns    5.0
```

I want to make it

```
critic  Claudia Puig    Gene Seymour    Jack Matthews   Lisa Rose   Mick LaSalle    Toby
title                       
Just My Luck    3.0 1.5 NaN 3.0 2.0 NaN
Lady in the Water   NaN 3.0 3.0 2.5 3.0 NaN
Snakes on a Plane   3.5 3.5 4.0 3.5 4.0 4.5
Superman Returns    4.0 5.0 5.0 3.5 3.0 4.0
The Night Listener  4.5 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 NaN
You Me and Dupree   2.5 3.5 3.5 2.5 2.0 1.0
```

and I used

```
movie_rating= ratings.pivot(index='critic', columns='title',values='rating')
```

but it created the title and critic at  the same column. 
how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas using isnull

```
df[df['You column with NaN'].isnull()]
```

This will return rows with NaN

```
df2 = df[df['You column with NaN'].isnull()]['Title']
```

Will return what you want,

One example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([range(3), [0, np.NaN, np.NaN], [0, 0, np.NaN], range(3), range(3)], columns=["Col_1", "Col_2", "Col_3"])
print df

   Col_1  Col_2  Col_3
0     0   1.0   2.0
1     0   NaN   NaN
2     0   0.0   NaN
3     0   1.0   2.0
4     0   1.0   2.0

print df[df['Col_3'].isnull()]
   Col_1  Col_2  Col_3
1     0   NaN   NaN
2     0   0.0   NaN
df2 =df[df['Col_3'].isnull()]['Col_2']
print df2
1    NaN
2    0.0
Name: Col_2, dtype: float64
```

### EDIT

I got your issue now, the main problem is the dataframe itself. When you used pivot, the column parameter is wrong...

You don't need to fix this problem though.

If I'm not wrong, now you want only the critic and movies, without the rating itself.

```
df_Toby = df.loc[df['critic'] == 'Toby']
```

This df['critic'] == 'Toby' will select all rows with the critic name

To return the titles you can select the column 'title'

```
df_Toby = df_Toby['title']
```

To subset the title and rating

```
df_Toby = df_Toby[['title', 'rating']]
```

you can use after that

```
exclude_Nan_df_Toby = df_Toby.dropna()
```

This will exclude all rows with NaN, and return only rows with a valid rating.

Cheers,

Comment: critic Toby
title 
Just My Luck NaN
Lady in the Water NaN
The Night Listener NaN

Comment: Well, can you run movie_rating_T.columns.values and tell me the result?

Comment: I put additional info

Comment: I want to get only movie name

Comment: What happens when you type: print(list(movie_rating_T))

Comment: @minmoica can you run this: movie_rating_T.columns.values?

Comment: array(['Claudia Puig', 'Gene Seymour', 'Jack Matthews', 'Lisa Rose',
       'Mick LaSalle', 'Toby'], dtype=object)

Comment: @minmoica, Can you show in your question movie_rating_T.head(). It seems that you can select the column ('Toby') but the row is really strange...

Comment: kaihami when you check my additional post. i used ratings.pivot to create new table. but during this process it create the 'title' and 'critic' column name in the same column. I think this is the reason. can you take a look at my additional post?

Comment: @minmoica fixed your issue?